# Mocking restTemplate returns null

Tags: java, spring, mocking, resttemplate

For some reason, the following test fails because "response" is null, but it should not, because I use the when() function to return an initialized object. Any idea how to fix it? This is the exact error:

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because "response" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because "response" is null
```

This is the test class:

```java
class UtilsControllerTest {

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate=mock(RestTemplate.class);
    @Test
    void checkPermission() {
        boolean permitted = true;

        ResponseEntity<PermissionResponseModel> response = ResponseEntity.ok(new PermissionResponseModel(permitted));

        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(String.class), any(Map.class), any(Class.class)))
                .thenReturn(response);

        UtilsController utilsController = new UtilsController();
        assertTrue(utilsController.checkPermission("69696969", Task.MAKE_REQUEST, restTemplate));
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).postForEntity(any(), any(), any());
    }

}
```

This is the implementation of UtilsController:

```java
public class UtilsController {
    private static final String authString = "Authorization";

    /**
     * Checks if the user is authorised to do a certain task.
     *
     * @param token the identification token
     * @param task  the task
     * @return true iff user is allowed, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean checkPermission(String token, Task task, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        HttpHeaders authHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        authHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        authHeaders.set(authString, token);
        String url = "http://localhost:8081/permission";

        PermissionRequestModel prm = new PermissionRequestModel();
        prm.setTask(task);
        HttpEntity<PermissionResponseModel> entity = new HttpEntity(prm, authHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<PermissionResponseModel> response =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, PermissionResponseModel.class);
        return response.getBody().isPermitted();
    }
}
```

I tried to mock the returned response entity, it did not work either. Still, the response was null. But in both cases, when I debug it, response has the right value, is not null.

Comment: You are registering behavior for a different `postForEntity` method then you are actually using.

Comment: How should I write it for the right entity? I tried writing it like this, but it still does not work:
`restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), eq(PermissionResponseModel.class))`

Comment: I managed to solve it, you were right. If I just write (any(), any(), eq(PermissionResponseModel.class) there are multiple functions that I could refer to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum said, I'm registering the behaviour for a different
`postForEntity` method. The fix is:

```java
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class)))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new PermissionResponseModel(permitted), HttpStatus.OK));
```